# How do I make Visual Studio 2015's CodeMap useable for Native C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, code-map

CodeMap looks like it would be incredibly useful, but I haven't been able to make it *useable* yet.  My most frequent use case is extracting functionality into new classes to clean things up, but despite appearing to be exactly what I need, I can't get it to tap into any of the things the IDE knows about.

Here are my biggest roadblocks:

- Making a new .dgml and adding even a single method requires connecting to the code index, a process which takes 5-10 minutes, and which requires a full rebuild regardless of what state the code is in at the time.  I can turn off the build, but how do I make the code stay indexed? Must it re-index the entire codebase again for each file?
- Once I successfully add a method, when I add another, no relations are ever detected. I want to map what calls what, and can only get relations when adding an entire project.  This would take me under 1s each using the Call Hierarchy functionality. What am I doing wrong that it can't obtain this information on its own?

I know I can do these things manually, but I might as well just be using View Call Hierarchy and Visio, which at least wouldn't make me index for every new file!

I haven't been able to find anything on the internet about issues with native C++ issues, just very high-level instructions on use.  Has anyone managed to make this thing work like professional software for a production native C++ project?